# Shibboleth + Facebook

Tags: facebook, shibboleth

I am developing a Facebook application to be used in a university (which already has a Shibboleth idProvider and many serviceProviders running).
How do I integrate shibboleth into facebook?

This is what I want to do:
- For someone who is NOT a student, he can only see/use the public data/services.
- For students, he can login using his University credentials (authenticated against university idProvider) and then use the private services.

Any pointers of how to achieve this?

Many thanks
Don

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is "more than one year old question" but I believe that some of future users of Stack may find response for this unanswered question useful.

Facebook provides [api for developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/), which can be quite easily used to implement Facebook <-> Shibboleth IdP integration

there is an IdP extension on the [Shibboleth Contributions site](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Contributions#Contributions-IdentityProviderExtensions) called Facebook Login Servlet, which enables [obtaining user attributes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) from Facebook.
Both binary file (with complete configuration description) and sources are avalible.

More information:
[Link to project site](http://apps.man.poznan.pl/trac/idp-facebook-integration/wiki), [SVN repo](https://apps.man.poznan.pl/svn/idp-facebook-integration/)

It's vital to understand how this extension work so be sure to read brief description which is available on project site.